# Problems with minted package in overleaf

Tags: minted, code, overleaf

I am using overleaf for my LaTeX document and I need to add a snippet of some Python code.
I have the following packages:

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{Latex/Classes/PhDthesisPSnPDF}
\input{Latex/Macros/MacroFile1}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{colortbl,multirow,hhline}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,enumitem,mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
      \textwidth 15cm
      \textheight 22cm
      \parindent 10pt
      \oddsidemargin 0.85cm
      \evensidemargin 0.37cm
\newcommand{\newchange}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}} 

\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
```

I am trying to add the Python code like this:

```
\begin{minted}{python}
class SOSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = "stackoverflow"
\end{minted}
```

I am getting this error:
[image]

How can I fix this?
Thanks!!

Comment: Do you have python and pygments installed?

Comment: I am using Overleaf

Comment: well, ok. But this error definitely pops up when you compile without having pygments. Try compile examples in overleaf-minted tutorial.

Comment: I tried a minimal document with the `article` class, `\usepackage{minted}` and your `minted` environment in the body. Everything worked fine. I'm afraid your cannot be debugged here, contact the Overleaf people.

Comment: @agukalpa Hello there! Tom from Overleaf Support Team here. Unfortunately, minted doesn't work in Overleaf if the main file of the project is in a subfolder and not in the top folder of the project. Is that the case for you please? If this doesn't help, you can reach me on Overleaf support email address and we can see what's going on there. Then if it's something worth sharing with others, I will make an answer here.

Comment: @yo' finally a useful answer for the problem I was having! thanks! maybe adding this information to [this](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Code_Highlighting_with_minted) page would help someone else :)

Comment: Hi @Majubs ! We're looking into ways how to make users aware if they try to use a feature that requires the main file to be in the top folder. We have to look at this as there's quite a number of such features unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Since this has no answer, and I actually solved my problem with this question, I'll post here in case someone else find it useful.

I had the same error as OP, and managed to get rid of it by adding

```
\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}
```

It compiled, but the code wasn't showing in the pdf. What really solved was @yo' comment:

> Unfortunately, minted doesn't work in Overleaf if the main file of the project is in a subfolder and not in the top folder of the project.

I imported this project from a template, and the main file was inside a folder, after changing everything to the top folder, things worked as expected!